# Simpler price.phtml

Tags: price, template

Does there exist, somewhere, a simpler version of price.phtml that does not have WEEE or tax-included implemented? These are features that are very rarely, if ever, used on a standard build as far as my work is concerned.

I have attempted to remove and refactor myself, and it works, which I will post as a potential answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: no support for:

- WEEE
- Display included tax
- Display of "both" incl and excl taxes
- No support for Grouped products
- No support for "minimal" price display or ranges

**File: app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/price.phtml**

```
<?php
$_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
$_taxHelper = $this->helper('tax');
/* @var $_coreHelper Mage_Core_Helper_Data */
/* @var $_taxHelper Mage_Tax_Helper_Data */
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_storeId = $_product->getStoreId();
$_store = $_product->getStore();
$_id = $_product->getId();
$_simplePricesTax = ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() || $_taxHelper->displayBothPrices());
$_minimalPriceValue = $_product->getMinimalPrice();
$_minimalPriceValue = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_minimalPriceValue));
$_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $_simplePricesTax);
$_convertedFinalPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getFinalPrice()));
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel();
$price = $_convertedFinalPrice;
$_inclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $price, true);
?>

<?php if ($price): ?>
    <div class="price-box">
        <p>
            <span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_inclTax, false) ?>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What happens when various config is selected in the back office for enabling/disabling tax or a grouped product is created?

Comment: Then this is not a suitable solution